# Server ignoring my setlocale settings

Tags: php, locale, wamp, gettext

I am dealing with this problem quite a while and this is not my first question to it, but still I can not get localization to work correctly.
I use WAMP server and php gettext.
A simple code I made for demonstration of my problem:

```
 /* dirs */
 $directory = realpath('../locale');
 $domain = 'messages';

 /* trying to find out correct setting - last one is winner */
 $locale ="ro";             
 $locale ="ro_utf8";
 $locale ="ro_RO";
 $locale ="ro_RO.UTF-8";
 $locale ="Romanian_Romania.1250";  

 putenv("LANG=".$locale);

 print setlocale( LC_ALL, $locale);
 setlocale( LC_ALL, $locale);

 bindtextdomain($domain, $directory);
 textdomain($domain);
 bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

 /* STRING TO BE TRANSLATED */
 echo _('string');
```

In `../locale` directory there are many folders like this - `$language_name/LC_MESSAGES/`. These contain corresponding .po and . mo files with translations like this:

```
msgid "string"
msgstr "string SK"
```

in `sk_SK` folder
or this

```
msgid "string"
msgstr "string RO"
```

in `ro`, `ro_RO`, `ro_RO.UTF8`, `ro_RO.UTF-8`, `romanian`, `Romanian_Romania`,  `Romanian_Romania.1250` folders.

And what document looks like:

> Romanian_Romania.1250 string SK

So you can see clearly - **I setlocale() to romanian**, yet my **text is translated using the translation in `sk_SK` directory**. What am I doing wrong?

Are there some functions I could use to get informations about $locale strings and directory names my server expects to find?

Answer (score 1):

try to do your code like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ro_RO','Romanian');
```

it had worked in my project

Answer (score 0):

You can help :

`locale -a`

And you can whach the language exist in your computer.

```
 sudo locale-gen pt_PT
 sudo locale-gen pt_PT.utf8
 sudo update-locale
```